# Privacy-preserving smart contracts: examples, tutorial, best practices?

Tags: contract-development, encryption, privacy, scalability

I want to make a proof-of-concept about privacy-preserving smart contracts. I know it's uneconomical to use encryption with Ethereum smart contracts.
Are there best practices about how to do that?
Could I use some kind of off-chain approach for that purpose, such as Enigma or truebit?
Some sample projects or tutorials would be a great help.

To give you more background:
I aim to store encrypted data in a smart contract and allow parties that fulfill certain criteria, e.g. who made a payment to the smart contract, to retrieve the decrypted data.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is several months old, but you can check this out:

https://blog.enigma.co/getting-started-with-the-enigma-protocol-a-complete-developers-guide-170b7dfa5c0f

In the article is described how to create a DApp solving the Yao's Millionaires problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yao%27s_Millionaires%27_Problem)